# NGINX Minecraft reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, ip, minecraft

I have a problem with Reverse Proxy to Minecraft. The problem is as follows. Proxy does not pass the IP of the person connecting, but the IP of the proxy so everyone on the server has the same IP.

```
    server {
        # Port number the reverse proxy is listening on
        listen  25565;
        # The original Minecraft server address
        proxy_pass  server.example.com:25565;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please ad this configuration to pass your nginx client ip

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```